# Best practice on Getting result of Bucketed Random Projection in pyspark

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

Currently, I have built a `BucketedRandomProjectionLSH` model in order to calculate the similarity of data by `approxNearestNeighbors`. The following code is like this.

```
df = sql_context.read.format("org.apache.spark.sql.cassandra").options(table="data", keyspace="spark").load()
brp = BucketedRandomProjectionLSH(inputCol="features", outputCol="hashes", bucketLength=2.0,
                                  numHashTables=3)
model = brp.fit(df)

df_collected = df.collect()

for x in df_collected:
    result = model.approxNearestNeighbors(df, x["features"], 30).collect()
    write(result)  ## save result to db
```

I'm thinking is there any method which can distribute the workload of the for loop

```
for x in df_collected:
    result = model.approxNearestNeighbors(df, x["features"], 30).collect()
    write(result)  ## save result to db
```

to each machines

I found  `foreach` or `foreachPartition` can do the job done but I have tried. They don't allow me to pass the rdd `df` there.

Is there any best practice on doing this kind of problem?

Comment: just try `df.rdd.foreach` instead of `df.foreach`

Comment: @Paul How to use the whole df inside foreach?